# BLE is not working in background - ios / swift

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, background, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm Facing a Problem with BLE process in Background. The device is connected correctly but the notification is not received in the right way. In fact, I'm following the next steps:

1. set the background modes
2. instantiate the Central Managers with a unique identifier of background mode

I just did it into a class which managed the ble

```
override init() {
    
    super.init()
    central = CBCentralManager.init(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey:"com.Imen.Identifier"])
    let options: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .sound];
    center.requestAuthorization(options: options) {
        (granted, error) in
        if !granted {
            print("no access to Central Manager Error")
        }
    }
  scan()
}
```

I don't know if I should Re-instantiate the central again in  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions !!!

3. set the delegate methods of CBCentralManager (for this one , I followed the doc [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html))

I see that I have to set willrestorestate method to notify the user that the device is connected

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, willRestoreState dict: [String: Any]) {
    print("will restore connection");
    var peripherals = dict[CBCentralManagerRestoredStatePeripheralsKey] as? [CBPeripheral] ?? []
    if (peripherals.count > 0 ){
        for peripheral in peripherals {
            peripherals.append(peripheral)
            peripheral.delegate = self;
            central.connect(peripheral)
        }
    } else {
        scan()
    }
    
}
```

**EDITED**
I added this following code into didFinishLaunchingWithOptions but the array of identifiers is nil
`    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

```
    if let peripheralManagerIdentifiers: [String] = launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.bluetoothCentrals] as? [String]{
        print("peripheralManagerIdentifiers ---> \(peripheralManagerIdentifiers)")
                for identifier in peripheralManagerIdentifiers{
                    if (identifier == "coom.Imen.Identifierr"){
                        bleManager.central = CBCentralManager.init(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey:identifier])
                    }
                }
            }

    return true
}`
```

I'm totally confused, thank you for any help

To Conclude: My main problem is when the device is in connected state and the app in the background, the user should be notified that there is a device near to him  and it is connected again:

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show relevant code as text, not images.  Do you instantiate your central manager in `didFinishLaunching`?  You talk about background mode, but your question is more to do with state restoration, which occurs after your app is terminated and the connected peripheral comes back into range

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3418066/paulw11 I tried to edit my post , what u think !!

Comment: Yes, you need to ensure that you create the class that creates your cbcentralmanager in `didFinishLaunching` If the launch options contains your cbcentralmidentifier https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW13

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3418066/paulw11 I reinstantiate the central manager in didFinishLaunching , but doesn't work !! any help please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1185169/simon-mcloughlin Any idea please !!

Comment: How are you testing state restoration?

Comment: In fact , I don't know exactly the appropriate way of testing state restoration, but the resotorestate method is not called in background !! I don't know why

Comment: That is why I want to understand what you *are doing*. State restoration is only invoked after your app has been terminated by iOS and then the connected peripheral comes back into range. This requires that you have a pending `connect` operation; you do this by connecting in `didDisconnect`.  Even knowing that state restoration has been invoked is tricky. You need to have logging set up or the debugger primed to connect to the task that iOS launches. State restoration isn't required for general background Bluetooth processing. Explain your test and results more clearly

Comment: Ok, I just read your edited question. I don't think what you are trying to do is anything to do with state restoration. Your final sentence says that "the peripheral is connected and you want to notify the user when it is connected again".  How can it connect again if it is already connected?  Do you mean you want to notify if the peripheral disconnects and then reconnected?  What code have you written to handle the disconnection/reconnection?  What do you have in `didDisconnect`?

Comment: Exactly ,  the scan of devices in the background is not working in appropriate way!! 
`
 func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        self.connectedPeripheral = nil
        bleManagerDelegate?.onPeripheralDisconnect(peripheral: peripheral, error: error)
    }`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code.  What does `onPeripheralDisconnect` do? Are you sure that `bleManagerDelegate` isn't `nil`?  How are you "scanning" in the background.  You can't scan for `nil` service in the background and you can't use duplicate scan events in the background. Discovery of a previously discovered peripheral will not be delivered to your app when it is in the background.